# Protecting some files from development in git

Tags: git

I want to setup git server with SugarCRM.
There are some files and folders needed to be protected and I want to allow only some to be able to developed etc.
How it is possible with git?

Comment: Put them in a different repository is all I can think of.

Comment: What do you mean by "protected?"

Comment: not being able to be developed, but should be there when anyone does a checkout

Comment: Are you hosting this repo on github or what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: no, i have my own private git server

Comment: Then there's no need to tag your question with github.

Comment: There is no lock file function for you to protect a specific file in git

Answer (score 1):

Put the protected files in a read-only submodule.

Or, use a pre-receive hook to enforce read-only on select files.

Or, have others develop on a different branch and don't merge any of the protected files.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [pre-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) and use that to make sure all files are in directories where your developers are allowed to write. You can use that hook on your server. It still allows users to commit the files (on their local branch) but they cannot be pushed to the server any more and the entire push will fail.

Answer (score -2):

If "protected" means "excluded from version control", then you can do this by adding them to [.gitignore](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) file.

Comment: .gitignore implies one person, "Some to be able" implies many--which would require the file to be included in version control.

Comment: No, i want them in the repository so that everyone can clone them. But I don't want them to be changed.